# How to access the ancestor node in the same XQuery?

Tags: xpath, xquery, zorba

```
<results>
{
    for $p in
    (
    for $o in doc("mondial-3.0.xml") /mondial/organization
    where fn:count($o/members)
    order by fn:count($o/members) descending
    return <organization>
            <name> {$o/@name/string()} </name>
            <abbreviation> {$o/@abbrev/string()} </abbreviation>
            <num_members> {fn:count($o/members)} </num_members>
            <members> {for $m in doc("mondial-3.0.xml") $o/members
            return <country> {mondial/country[@id=$m/@country]/@name/string()} </country>} </members>
       </organization>
    )[position() < 10]
    return $p
}
</results>
```

I am unable to access the ancestor node in this problem as I have got an id stored of a parameter and now I want to match the id of that parameter and get a name of the parameter.

I am not getting any output for this. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

XML FILE :-

The link for the xml file is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kroell/hsrm-mi-2semester-markuplanguage/master/Abgabe2/Aufgabe2/mondial-3.0.xml

Comment: I think sample xml to test the XQuery against maybe more useful than the dtd at this point

Comment: I have added the link of the xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you posted, the root element of the XML is `mondial` not `users`, so I'd use `mondial` in this answer. Notice that ***member of organization*** and ***country*** are linked by ***country id***, so you can do as follow to get country name of every `member` element :

```
<f> 
{
    for $m in $o/members
    return <g> {mondial/country[@id=$m/@country]/@name/string()} </g>
} 
</f>
```

Here is the complete working query. Tested in http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery using XML from the link posted in question as input :

```
<a>
{
    for $p in
    (
    for $o in /mondial/organization
    where fn:count($o/members)
    order by fn:count($o/members) descending
    return <b>
            <c> {$o/@name/string()} </c>
            <d> {$o/@abbrev/string()} </d>
            <e> {fn:count($o/members)} </e>
            <f> {for $m in $o/members
            return <g> {/mondial/country[@id=$m/@country]/@name/string()} </g>} </f>
       </b>

    )[position() < 10]
    return $p
}
</a>
```

Comment: This works well in all of tester or online editor but throws an error for zorba.         Error message: "dynamic error [err:XPDY0002]: "context item": undeclared variable" inside the content of <g>

Comment: @crash maybe you just forgot to use `doc("mondial-3.0.xml")` in your actual XQuery, no?

Comment: @crash update your question with the latest query, *maybe* I can spot the problem (not familiar with zoba tho)

Comment: Nah, you haven't use `doc(...)` in this part: `return <country> {doc("mondial-3.0.xml")/mondial/country[@id=$m/@country]/@name/string()} </country>}`

Comment: Yeah, I had tried this. It does not give any output on the console.

Answer (score 0):

You don't define the desired output of your query so it's hard to tell you why your query isn't giving the desired output; but there are several things about the query that suggest it's completely wrong.

Firstly, `$o` is always a single `<mem>` element, so `fn:count($o)` is always 1, so the use of this expression in the `where` and `order by` clauses cannot have any useful effect.

Secondly, the expression used to produce the content of the `<f>` element looks all wrong because it doesn't depend in any way on the value of `$o`.

Comment: Yeah, i got the mistakes which had committed. I have corrected the code now but still I am not able be print correct content of <g>.

Comment: I can't help you with that as I have no idea what the correct value of `<g>` is.